# Python Script Taking Up Memory After Finished Running

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a very short python script:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('max_rows', 500)

table_list = ['company', 'partnership', 'reward', 'group']
table_dict = {}

for table in table_list:
    with open(f'pickled_dataframes/{table}_df.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        table_dict[table] = pickle.load(f)
print('Done')
```

When I run the script it appears in my Mac's activity monitor and takes up a bunch of memory (since I'm loading in a few huge pandas dataframes). When the script stops running, however, the script continues to take up this memory. And if I run the script again it will appear twice and neither instance will disappear unless I manually kill the process in activity monitor.

[image]

When I manually kill the process after running the script - the following message appears in my sublime text output box:

[image]

Any help diagnosing and solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you running this script?

Comment: Running it in sublime text directly

Comment: Try running it from the Terminal.

Comment: Ah that solved it - would you be able to explain why this works in terminal but not when running out of sublime? Just trying to understand it

Comment: What you're seeing is Sublime Text's window for running python, it's not the actual `python3` process.